# Sporadically missing "click to add a new hyperlink"

Tags: 2010, list, migration, master-page

We just migrated from 2007 to 2010 and changed our stylesheets to use v4. We have a list of over 1000 items with a few "Link URL" columns. Occasionally when editing the item, the link url field would not show the "Click to add a new hyperlink" in order to add a link. This "Click to add.." shows for other hyperlink fields in the same record, but not for this particular field. For the same field, it shows in other records. So very sporadic. Sometimes the link value vanishes and there is no way I can add it back unless I delete and readd, which is painful as it seems to happen frequently. Anyone seen such an issue?

Comment: More details no solution yet: The issue lies with the Publishing Hyperlink site column type. I created a list from scratch containing only a field of publishing hyperlink type. First time I enter some link. Then when I edit it, I have to use the Link Tools tab at the top which provides a few more options - Select Link, Remove Link, Url, Desc. If I enter a new value in the url field, it does not update the original list field. The desc is updated though as tooltip. Also if I do Remove Link, I cannot add the url anymore, because the "click here to add new url" is gone. Anyone seen this?

Answer (score 1):

I did double check that publishing hyperlink has issues updating the values and the link vanishes, without a chance to add a new link. Very likely a SharePoint bug. However I wrote a small script that would update the link via powershell. I have updated the solution in my blog vasya10.wordpress.com.